# Pandas: combining duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas, sum, unique, median

I have a pandas series that I would like to combine in three different ways. The series is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4]
quantities = [10,0,2,6,7,2,8,0]
series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)
```

Clearly the timestamps have `3 values of 1`, `1 value of 2`, `3 values of 3` and `1 value of 1`. I would like to generate the following series:

**1. Sum of the duplicate index values:**

```
pd.Series([12,6,17,0], index=[1,2,3,4])
```

**2. Median of the duplicate index values:**

```
pd.Series([2,6,7,0], index=[1,2,3,4])
```

**2. The number of duplicate index values:**

```
pd.Series([3,1,3,1], index=[1,2,3,4])
```

In `numpy` I would achieve this using a `unique_elements_to_indices` method:

```
from typing import Dict
import numpy as np
def unique_elements_to_indices(array: np.array) -> Dict:
    mapping = {}
    for unique_element in np.unique(array):
        mapping[unique_element] = np.where(array == unique_element)[0]
    return mapping
```

... and then I would loop through the `unique_elements` and use `np.where` to locate the `quantities` for that given `unique_element`.

Is there away to achieve this quickly in pandas, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible use functions `sum`, `median` for separate outputs with parameter `level=0` for aggregate by index:

```
print (series.sum(level=0))
print (series.median(level=0))
```

But generaly aggregate by index with function:

```
print (series.groupby(level=0).sum())
print (series.groupby(level=0).median())
#difference between count and size is count exclude NaNs values
print (series.groupby(level=0).size())

print (series.groupby(level=0).count())
```

If need all together to new DataFrame use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with list of aggregate functions:

```
print(series.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum', 'median', 'size']))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea which is best/fastest to use?

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis - If need all output in DataFrame, best is last.

Comment: In pandas v0.24.1, I get the following error for `series.count(level=0)`: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1579, in count
    lev = self.index.levels[level]
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'**

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis - Sorry, not tested properly, You are right. It working only for some fuunctions like `sum, mean, median, max, min`. For `size and count` not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.groupby` for this:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4]
quantities = [10,0,2,6,7,2,8,0]
sr = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)

print(sr.groupby(sr.index).sum())
print(sr.groupby(sr.index).median())
print(sr.groupby(sr.index).count())
```

Comment: Thanks, but you were just beaten unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with pandas library then advisable to convert your data into dataframe. The Easiest way is as below in pandas

```
timestamps = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4]
quantities = [10,0,2,6,7,2,8,0]
d = {'quantities': quantities, 'timestamps': timestamps}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.groupby('timestamps').sum().reset_index()
```

The Similar way you can also use other function as well. Kindly let me know if this works for you.